# What is SystemVerilog equivalent for VHDL fixed_pkg and float_pkg?

Tags: vhdl, system-verilog

The VHDL fixed_pkg and float_pkg provide some very interesting functionality. The fixed_pkg is supported by some synthesis tools but the float_pkg is not supported at all. They basically provide a capability to declare a array of std_logic with positive and negative indices. This way one can create fixed point numbers and floating point numbers represented as array of std_logic.

I have not found anything like fixed_pkg and float_pkg for SystemVerilog so far. If something exists of this nature, where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can seemlessly use real, shortreal for float values whereas int for fixed data type values to perform arithmetic operations on variables.

Below is the note from systemverilog-3.1a:

"The real and shortreal types are represented as described by IEEE 754-1985, an IEEE standard for floating point numbers (See [K1] in
Annex K)"

As added in snip below, you can see sign, mantissa and exponent part structure.
[image]

Comment: [can anyone provide a good example of operator overloading in system verilog?](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/can-anyone-provide-good-example-operator-overloading-system-verilog), [Does SystemVerilog support operator overloading?](https://verificationacademy.com/forums/systemverilog/does-questasim-support-operator-overloading)
 Never implemented and It's certainly not found in IEEE Std 1800-2017. Your quote from 7.17 Operator overloading represents illusory features.

Comment: [SystemVerilog operator overloading (bind construct) #633](https://github.com/verilator/verilator/issues/633)

Comment: ok, I am very confused now, in VHDL we can bit vector with negative index representive fixed point numbers, I assume nothing like this can be done with SystemVerilog? Also, what is the proper way to convert between a vector of bits and float and vice versa? The typedef struct thing you presented is completely new information for me actually.

Comment: @quantum231 bit vector is just concatenated bits. It depends on us what data type we define for it. For conversions "fx pt <->float pt" there are readily available IP cores by IntelFPGA/Xilinx. 

https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/floating_point/v7_1/pg060-floating-point.pdf

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/programmable/683750/20-1/list-of-floating-point-ip-cores.html

IPs seamlessly supports fx <->float pt with option to manipulate bit vector width as per your need. i/p and o/p can be fixed or float anything.